# Finding set of colours that are distinguishable to each other

Tags: graph, colors

I am writing a graph plotting program. I thus am looking ways to obtain colours that are distinguishable to each other in order to plot various graphs in one cell.

Is there an algorithm or some website that obtains rgb values that matches this criteria?

EDIT: I am looking for 16 different colours

Comment: You might find some information on sites which describe how different kinds of colour blindness affect perception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an automatic solution, you can take one color as the base color and obtain good matching colors by changing the hue in the HSV/HSB color space. If you need 4 colors for example you could rotate the hue by 90° for each color.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of lines on the graph isn't too large (i.e. you can pick colours by hand), I rather like [this (http://colorschemedesigner.com/)](http://colorschemedesigner.com/) for choosing colours that work together, but stand out from each other.